# Queries to find data between two dates

Tags: sql

I have a table that has customer_name, customer_id, order_id, order_date, ship_date and I am asked to find which orders have same day shipping from the year 2013 and 2016.

```
SELECT customer_id, order_date, ship_date
FROM orders
WHERE order_date = ship_date;
```

The code I entered above works fine but I cannot figure out how to find which orders have same day shipping between 2013-2016.

Comment: `WHERE order_date = ship_date AND order_date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2016-12-31' ` should work

Comment: What DBMS? They all operate a little differently.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add another WHERE that has this: (Just change the dates to what you want of course)

```
       order_date BETWEEN
          TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-01-01 12:00:00' , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') AND TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-02-01 12:00:00' , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `BETWEEN`

```
SELECT customer_id, order_date, ship_date
FROM orders
WHERE order_date = ship_date
AND order_date BETWEEN TO_TIMESTAMP('2013-01-01 00:00:01' , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') AND TO_TIMESTAMP('2016-12-31 23:59:59' , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server, you can do

```
SELECT customer_id, order_date, ship_date
FROM orders
WHERE order_date = ship_date
AND DATEPART(YEAR, order_date) BETWEEN 2013 AND 2016
```